# What is the regex for finding a of a piece of text in a particular format

Tags: java, regex

What is the regex for finding if a piece of text is in a particulate format?

Format should follow:
`AAAA-123` or `AAAA123` (with or without the dash)

Where the first 4 characters are letters in the range A-M and the following  3 characters are numbers with a max of 299.

Example:

`ABCD-299` would match

and

`ABZR-301` would not match

Comment: This seems like a bad use-case for a regular expression. Test the first four characters, and the last three characters follow your rules.

Comment: [A-M]{4}-?[0-2][0-9]{2}

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think this is a perfect case for regex

Comment: Okay, but [now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: Not sure why this would be a bad use-case for regex. Even if you were to just test the first four characters and then the last three... You'd also have to check what's between them (nothing or just a hyphen). And what would you use to test the first four and the last three? I'm curious to see Elliot's non-regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[A-M]{4}-?[0-2][0-9]{2}
```

Basically:
`[A-M]{4}` = 4 of any letters A-M
`-?` = an optional dash
`[0-2]` = a single 0,1, or 2
`[0-9]{2}` = two of any number

limiting the first number to `0-2` effectively limits your number to 299, and allows for 000-299

i'm not sure if you are searching for this in a string or checking that a string equals exactly this... and that context might change how you use the above. for example, if you are testing a string you'll want to wrap it with `^` and `$`

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I actually under it better now

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-M]{4}-?[0-2][0-9]{2}$
```

^ means beginning of string

[] define a group of potential matches.  In this case uppercase A all the way to uppercase M (hyphen is a special char when within [] to denote a range) (note the range utilizes ascii http://www.asciitable.com/  so if you did A-z it would include all those non alphanumeric characters between.

{} define count.  in this case *exactly* 4.  you can define a range like {1,3} which means 1 to 3, or {,7} at most 7, or {5,} at least 5

and the ? means that the char before is may or may not be there. in this case the hyphen.

$ means end of string

the ^ and $ are necessary i think. otherwise that regex will match AAAAAAAA-2342347474

anyways, read up on regex. they can be powerful and fun.  http://regexr.com/

Comment: I thought `^` means not

Comment: @MitchellGharechedaghi `^` may have 2 special meanings. If it is placed inside character set and it is first character like `[^a-z]` it is negation of such character set. So in this case `[^a-z]` represents any character which is *not* in `a-z` range. But if it is placed outside of any character set then it means anchor representing start of text (it can also be set to represent start of line, but you will need to use multiline flag).